# Only last VAO is drawn

Tags: opengl

I want to create a VAO for every 3D Object in my program.

I create two VAO's:

```
//in some method 1
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao1);

//in some method 2
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao2);
```

then for earch VAO I create 2 VBO's:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao1);
glGenBuffers(2, vbos1);
glBindVertexArray(0);
//and the same for vao2, vbos2
```

then I send the data to the gpu:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos1[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(positions1), positions1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos1[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices1), indices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
//and the same for vao2, vbos2, indices2
```

Then I do the same thing for vao2.

Now only vao2 is drawn.
If I switch the

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao2);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao1);
```

Then only the vao1 is drawn.

I draw the vaos via:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao1);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

//in another method
glBindVertexArray(vao2);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

It makes no difference in which order I draw them, send the data to the gpu or initialize the buffers.

Why is that so?

Comment: you have skiped the second VAO source code what if the bug is there? Also where are you rendering I do not see any calls related to it ... also how vao1,2 is declared ?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: This question is just to know if my theory is true or not. I just want to know if it makes a difference in which order the vao's are generated.

Comment: @ArwedMett ok you added the rendering stuff looks OK to me ... but still you have not included the `vao?,vbo?` declarations  there is a possibility they could overlap if wrongly declared. also still missing the `vao2,vbo2` code chunks they are copies so make sure you do not have copy typos in there (that is why I ask for them.... they are hard to spot by their author because of memory vision). Your problem description suggest wrong declaration ....

Answer (score 0):

Right: the order of creating VAOs makes no difference.

Among other things, a VAO stores the buffer binding. You don't need to bind a buffer each time you draw or update data. Just bind the VAO.

If the whole data fits in GPU memory you can update data only once, likely at buffer+VAO creation and binding. If not, then binding the VAO also makes the buffer "associated" in that VAO ready for receiving data.